# Constraints in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a situation where I try to have all of my buttons in the middle of the screen. Space between buttons is ok, aspect ratio is ok, but i have a problem with having it all in the middle of the screen.

Base screan looks like that:
[Here everything is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKgrC.jpg)

[Here is a preview of other dispaly sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zsQB.jpg)

Do you have any sugestion, how can I center it?

Comment: you need to provide more info. What kind of constraints did you gave to the buttons?

Comment: probably because you did set up the vertical constraints incorrectly. Align the center views to the center of the superview and align the rest of the squares to the two center squares

Comment: @luk2302 it is work! thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the middle buttons add a constraint which centers them vertically in the middle. On the row above and below add a constrain with a margin relative to the buttons on the middle row.

You could also place them in a container and center this in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 7, you can use StackView ! StackView will easily handle your buttons as shown on your images. Check the WWDC 2015 video about AutoLayout or this tutorial on raywenderlich that show how to use StackView. 
Here is the link [2015-12-14] http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views